# How to use a loop to read the number of consecutive duplicates

Tags: python

Consider this data sequence: "3 11 5 5 5 2 4 6 6 7 3 -8". Any value that is the same as the immediately preceding value is considered a CONSECUTIVE DUPLICATE. In this example, there are three such consecutive duplicates: the 2nd and 3rd 5s and the second 6. Note that the last 3 is not a consecutive duplicate because it was preceded by a 7. Write some code that uses a loop to read such a sequence of non-negative integers, terminated by a negative number. When the code finishes executing, the number of consecutive duplicates encountered is printed. In this case,3 would be printed.

ASSUME the availability of a variable, stdin, that references a Scanner object associated with standard input.

In python!! I've tried to solve this in so many different ways and can't. How can I put the first and second number from the input into a variable?

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "write some code that uses ...": this sentence alone made me downvote.

Comment: "I've tried to solve this in so many different ways and can't." Well tell us a little bit about them and maybe we can point you in the right direction. Nobody's going to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

This was presumably a Java problem (based on the mention of stdin and Scanner).

Why would you use a loop in Python?

```
>>> s=list(map(int,"3 11 5 5 5 2 4 6 6 7 3 -8".split()))
>>> s2=s[0:1]+[n for i,n in enumerate(s[1:]) if n != s[i]]
>>> s2
[3, 11, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 3, -8]
>>> len(s)-len(s2)
3
```

Different solutions for different languages.

And if you actually need to read a list of ints from stdin

```
s=list(map(int,input().split()))
```

will do it for Python 3